# select statement with only rows which have set true in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables

```
activity 
id | user_id | time | activity_id 
1  | 1       |      | 3 
2  | 1       |      | 1

and preferences
user_id | running | cycling | driving
1       | TRUE    | FALSE   | FALSE

i need result set of

id | user_id | time | 
2  | 1       |      |
```

i only need rows from first table whose values are set true in preferences table.
e.g activity_id for running is 1 which is set true in preferences table, so it returns while others doesn't.

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM activity AS t1, friends_pref AS t2
WHERE ((t1.activity_id =1 AND t2.running =1) OR( t1.activity_id =3 AND t2.cycling =1))  AND
t1.id = 1

Comment: @user3481679 Edit your question instead.

Comment: It would be easier if the data were relational. For example, how do you figure out that an activity_id of 1 is running?

Comment: i have no logical reply ...... i have used 1 for running thats why i am stuck because i am not finding relation between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the schema, it would be better like this:

```
activity
id | name
1  | running
2  | cycling
3  | driving

user_activity 
id | user_id | time | activity_id 
1  | 1       |      | 3 
2  | 1       |      | 1

preferences
user_id | activity_id
1       | 1
```

A row in preferences indicates a `TRUE` value from your schema. No row indicates a `FALSE`.

Then your query would simply be:

```
SELECT ua.id, ua.user_id, ua.time
  FROM user_activity ua
  JOIN preferences p ON ua.user_id = p.user_id
       AND ua.activity_id = p.activity_id
```

If you want to see the activity name in the results:

```
SELECT ua.id, ua.user_id, ua.time, activity.name
  FROM user_activity ua
  JOIN preferences p ON ua.user_id = p.user_id
       AND ua.activity_id = p.activity_id
  JOIN activity ON ua.activity_id = activity.id
```

Comment: it will increase my table length to 8n (n for each user), because i have 8 activities for a user . is it will be okay ?

Comment: That should be no problem. You might be giving up a little extra storage space but you gain the advantage that you don't have to modify your queries when you add a new activity. You simply add a new row to the `activity` table.

Answer (score 0):

What I would probably do is join the tables on a common column, looks like `user_id` is a common column in this case, which gives access to the columns in both tables to query against in the where clause of the query.

Which type of join depends on what information you want from preferences

[Handy Visual Guide for joins](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg)

So you could query

`SELECT * FROM activity LEFT JOIN preferences ON activity.user_id = preferences.user_id WHERE preferences.columnIWantToBeTrue = true`

I'm using `left join` since you mentioned you want the values from the first table based on the second table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM activity as t1,preferences as t2 WHERE (t1.activity_id = 1 and t2.running = 1)
                                                      
 and (t1.user_id =1 and t2.user_id = 1)

Comment: i am getting result of one activity from this but i need all those activities are are set true .

Comment: If possible go with Mike B's redesign of the schema and layout of the tables to make them more relational -- that will make everything a lot easier to use down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Mike B has the right answer. The relational model relates rows together by common values.

You've got a table named `activity` with an `id` column which looks like the primary key. The column name `activity_id` would typically be the name of a column in another table that is a foreign key to the `activity` table, referencing `activity.id`.

It looks like you've used the `activity_id` column in the `activity` table as a reference to either "running", "cycling" or "driving".

It's possible to match `activity.activity_id = 1` with `"running"`, but this is a bizarre design.

Here's an example query:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.user_id
     , a.time
  FROM activity a
  JOIN preferences p 
    ON p.user_id = a.user_id
   AND (  ( p.running = 'TRUE' AND a.activity_id = 1 )
       OR ( p.cycling = 'TRUE' AND a.activity_id = 2 )
       OR ( p.driving = 'TRUE' AND a.activity_id = 3 )
       )
```

But, again, this is a bizarre design.

As a start, each table in your database should have rows that represent either an **entity** (a person, place, thing, concept or event that can be uniquely identified, is important, and we need to store information about), or a **relationship** between the entities.

From the limited information we have about your use case, the entities appear to be "user", an "activity_type" (running, cycling, driving), an "activity" (an amount of time, for a user and an activity_type) and some user "preference" about which activity_types the user prefers.

See the answer from Mark B for a possible schema design.